# Searching database where first letter equals number or symbol

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have the query set up to search the table for usernames starting with a specific letter.

My query is this

```
if(isset($_POST['search']) || (isset($_GET['search']))){
if($_GET['search'] && !$_POST['search']){
if($_GET['search'] == "!"){
   $search = //What here for number and symbol check;
}
   else
   {
      $search = $_GET['search'];
   }
      $search = $_GET['search'];
}
elseif($_POST['search'] && !$_GET['search'])
{
   $search = $_POST['search'];
}

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE CONCAT(?, '%') OR id LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') LIMIT $start, $limit");
```

it works fine for all letters a-z, but I need to also check for those users who for some reason decide to start their usernames with numbers or symbols (client didn't want me to block special chars on registration) so how can I do a check for this?

Comment: Did you properly set the encoding in all places? Webpage, PHP script, database connection, database tables? If yes, it should work, no matter which characters you are after.

Comment: @Sven its coming from a link. I have a link for a,b,c...#,etc when they click on the link for # it sends them to `link.php?search=!` I need to define that search as searching for all numbers and symbols

Comment: You don't say what, if anything, is wrong with the code above?

Comment: @eggyal there is nothing wrong with the code, I am needing to know how to search for all symbols and numbers if `$_GET['search'] == !`

Comment: You cannot reuse your current query, because basically what you need to do is to search for any username or ID that starts either with A or B - your current query does not support this, you can only search for A in a query, or B in another, but not "A or B" in the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to look into Regular Expressions with mysql.  You need to search for something that is not 'alpha': [[:alpha:]]    Alpha - any letter. Equivalent to [a-z] and [A-Z]
Check out this link here for more help: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/MySQL_Regular_Expression_Searches